# Syntax error or access violant 1064

Tags: php, mysql, database

I don't see any problem in this code, is there any solution in giving php access to database?

```html
<?php 
    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=xxx;dbname=xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }
    
    $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM users');
    $r = $query->fetch();
    echo 'pre', print_r($r), '</pre>';
?>
```

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1
>   –

Comment: give the full error message

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1

Comment: try adding a `;` after dbname=xxx. Like this `$db = new PDO('mysql:host=xxx;dbname=xxx;', 'xxx', 'xxx');`